# Using NuGet without .sln or .csproj files

Tags: vbscript, nuget, hp-uft, nuget-package-restore, nuget-spec

I am currently working in a UFT project, using the VBScript language.
This project does not have a .sln or even .csproj files, because of this i am using the nuget.exe.
I want to use NuGet to manage binaries. I am already able to push a NuGet package to the repository, however I can not update or install it.

This is how my project looks like(I know its a bit different and is located on c:):

[image]

So it happens that I searshed on the internet but there are not even one project that looks like mine, most of them are done on Visual Studio.

Could you help me on how to use NuGet in a project like this one?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not just using `UFT` to manage your UFT solution?

Comment: Is it possible to do this? we use the UFT to do our automation test scripts. Actually it is the first time I work with UFT and when I arrive to the project things were already done this way.

Comment: If you open the application for `UFT`, you can then open the solution inside the application, yes.

Comment: Thanks Dave for your help, I will give this idea to my team... Let's see.